# How to write a step function using IF functions

Tags: excel, if-statement, worksheet-function

I have 3 ranges of numbers and the answer depends on the range.

```
75-79 -> 0.255
80-84 -> 0.327
85+   -> 0.559
```

I tried to create an equation that accounts for the ranges by using nested `IF` functions, but Excel states that I have entered too many arguments for this function. Below is the equation that I entered that is not working. (X2 contains the number)

```
=IF(X2=75,X2<=79,0.255,IF(X2=80,X2<=84,0.327,IF(X2>=85,0.559,0)))
```

I also tried to enter the range of numbers into another sheet - `Age`, and got an error `#Value!`.

```
=IF(X2=Age!A1:A5,0.257,IF(X2=Age!A6:A10,0.327,IF(X2=Age!A11:A33,0.559,0)))
```

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php

Comment: if you don't insist on using `IF`, then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18727766/11107541

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
=IF(X2>=85,0.559,IF(X2>=80,0.327,IF(X2>=75,0.255,-1)))
```

Explanation:

```
=IF(X2>=85,                  'If the value is in the highest bracket
      0.559,                 'Use the appropriate number
      IF(X2>=80,             'Otherwise, if the number is in the next highest bracket
           0.327,            'Use the appropriate number
           IF(X2>=75,        'Otherwise, if the number is in the next highest bracket
              0.255,         'Use the appropriate number
              -1             'Otherwise, we're not in any of the ranges (Error)
             )
        )
   )
```

Comment: VeeArr,
Thank you very much for the equation and the detailed explanation. I know it helped me understand why the equation had to be written that way. Hopefully it will help others too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the AND function for the multiple conditions:

```
=IF(AND(A2>=75, A2<=79),0.255,IF(AND(A2>=80, X2<=84),0.327,IF(A2>=85,0.559,0)))
```

Comment: Thank you Tom. I had played around with the AND function and couldn't make that work either. Looking at your finished equation, I now know that I was mixing parts of the AND function into a normal IF statement and that was just one of the mistakes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your formula should be of the form `=IF(X2 >= 85,0.559,IF(X2 >= 80,0.327,IF(X2 >=75,0.255,0)))`. This simulates the `ELSE-IF` operand Excel lacks. Your formulas were using two conditions in each, but the second parameter of the `IF` formula is the value to use if the condition evaluates to `true`. You can't chain conditions in that manner.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy. Your explanation was almost as good as the equation itself. These If statements are finally starting to make sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

Very simply put:

```
=IF(C7>100,"Profit",IF(C7=100,"Quota Met","Loss"))
```

The first `IF` Statement, if true will input Profit, and if false will lead on to the next `IF` statement and so forth :)

I only have basic formula knowledge but it's working so I will accept I am right!