# IF function with 3 conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm looking to create a formula with 3 conditions. It is currently only working with 2 conditions. Here's what I'm looking for:

`E9` has a number

If the number is `21+` then I want it to show Text `1`

If the number is between `5 and 21`, then I want it to show Text `2`

If the number is below `5`, then I want it to show Text `3`

This is what I currently have:

```
=IF(E9>21,"Text 1",IF(E9<21,E9>5,"Text 2")
```

When I try and add the final condition, it gives me an error that I've entered too many arguments for this function. When the number is below 5 it shows False.

I would prefer a solution that does not use `VLOOKUP`.

I'm not understanding why it's saying this is not allowed, I have another IF function with 5 nested formulas that works just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a step function using IF functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113420/how-to-write-a-step-function-using-if-functions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
=IF(E9>21,"Text 1",IF(AND(E9>=5,E9<=21),"Test 2","Text 3"))
```

Note I assume you meant `>=` and `<=` here since your description skipped the values `5` and `21`, but you can adjust these inequalities as needed.

Or you can do it this way:

```
=IF(E9>21,"Text 1",IF(E9<5,"Text 3","Text 2"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `INDEX` and `MATCH` for binning. Easier to maintain if we have more bins.

```
=INDEX({"Text 1","Text 2","Text 3"},MATCH(A2,{0,5,21,100}))
```

[image]

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer.  INDEX, MATCH and array values are too often overlooked in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

```
=if([Logical Test 1],[Action 1],if([Logical Test 2],[Action 1],if([Logical Test 3],[Action 3],[Value if all logical tests return false])))
```

Replace the components in the square brackets as necessary.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, and it does with the exception of values that increase. It shows Down whether the value in B2 is greater or less than C2. Here is the formula.

=IF(B2>C2,"Down",IF(B2<C2,"Up",IF(B2=C2,"No Change",)))

Essentially, if the value in C2 is greater than B2, show "Up", if less than, show "Down", and if they are equal, "no change". Help!

Comment: For some reason I always get stuck with if functions longer then two, this is really useful, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the 5 through 21 part:

```
=IF(E9>21,"Text1",IF(E9>4,"Text2","Text3"))
```