# Complex logical test in IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make an IF statement with three arguments, this is for a spreadsheet that keeps track of my TV shows. If there's a date in the "On Break" column then that date needs to get subtracted from the current date , and if there's nothing in the "On break" column then it has to show nothing. (I have this working).

But, now I'm trying to figure out if I can create another argument that lets me fill in `TBA` (To Be Confirmed, for TV shows that are on break but no new episode date yet confirmed) and when I fill in `TBA` it also has to show nothing. If I fill in `TBA` now I get an error. Here are some screenshots. note that I am using the Dutch version of Excel so IF = ALS.

[Screenshot of what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnQlu.jpg)
[image: Screenshot of what I currently have]

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you looked at this question: "[*IF function with 3 conditions*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18708561/1364007)"?

Comment: @pnuts - I deliberately didn't flag as duplicate because I wasn't sure: the intent of my comment was as a hint rather than a flag..