# Lookup a value if the # fall between two #

Tags: lookup, between, lookup-tables

I want to know what would be the best formula to use or lookup for:

I want to lookup a number, for example 572, which will be between Column A = From and Column B = Less Than and have the result that is in Column C

If you look at the attached image, when I lookup 572 it would be between 571 (Column A) and 575.01 (Column B) and I want it to give me the result of 8.20 (column C)

[image: screenshot of a spreadsheet]

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Excel; this belongs to SU

Comment: Possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727766/excel-multiple-ranges-need-different-answers-for-each-range