# EXCEL need different answers for each range, MULTIPLE RANGES

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

NEED HELP FIGURING OUT THIS FORMULA PLEASE!!!

- IF P4 is ABOVE "25,000" BUT BELOW "29,999" THEN AVERAGE (P4 VALUE , 2) *.035
- IF P4 is ABOVE "30,000" BUT BELOW "39,999" THEN AVERAGE (P4 VALUE , 2) *.05
- IF P4 is ABOVE "40,000" BUT BELOW "49,999" THEN AVERAGE (P4 VALUE , 2) *.065
- IF P4 is ABOVE "50,000" BUT BELOW "79,999" THEN AVERAGE (P4 VALUE , 2) *.0725
- IF P4 is ABOVE "80,000" BUT BELOW "124,999" THEN AVERAGE (P4 VALUE , 2) *.0575
- IF P4 is ABOVE "125,000" THEN AVERAGE P4 VALUE / 2 *.035

Comment: And what have you tried?  Also a FYI, Typing in all caps is considered yelling and can be taken poorly.

Comment: Also the `AVERAGE (P4 VALUE , 2)` does not make sense,  Are you say you want the average of 2 and the value in P4, as in P4 is 4 so the answer would be 3?

Comment: WELL, HAVE YOU TRIED CONVERTING YOUR REQUIREMENTS TO A FORMULA? LIKE `IF(AND(P4>X,P4<Y), "THEN THIS", "ELSE THIS")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've tried multiple different "if" clauses and can't get it to work, I have been googling for 2+ hours and can't find anything to help.

Comment: I would do this with a lookup table honestly. Use a VLOOKUP to import the appropriate value.

Comment: @ScottCraner P4/2. (example of {p4} 25,368 / 2) * .035....

Comment: What if P4 is below 25000

Comment: @urdearboy P4 will never be below 25000 in this sheet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EXCEL Multiple Ranges - need different answers for each range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727766/excel-multiple-ranges-need-different-answers-for-each-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table that stores the thresholds for your values and then use a `VLOOKUP` to import to appropriate multiplier. The benefit of this format is you can easily view and modify the mapping as needed.

Also, you don't need to test above and below conditions - the approximate match will handle that, as well as the bounds of your data, for you quit nicely

Note anything under 25K will produce error but anything over 125K will give correct multiplier of .035

---

```
=P2*VLOOKUP(P2,$A$2:$B$7,2,TRUE)/2
```

[image]

*Where `$A$2:$B$7` references the table mapping*

Answer (score 1):

Use CHOOSE(MATCH()) to return the correct multiplier:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(P4,{25000,30000,40000,50000,80000,125000}),.035,.05,.065,.0725,.0575,.035)*P4/2
```

[image]

Comment: It returns the correct multiplier as per your text.  See Edit.  The picture just contains the multiplier part.

Comment: I like the formula option more as long as the ranges & multiplier values are constant. IMO, if they change then making a table to manage the mapping is easier but I doubt that's the case

Comment: @ChristianRobertHammond Then you need to explain the formula better.  Because `$35,928.00/2 * 0.05 = 898.2` not `628.78`

Comment: @ScottCraner my original formula was off, thank you for your help!